# Simple Form bootstrap customize collection_radio_buttons field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have this collection_radio_buttons field which has been customized a bit to show icons, but now for some reason the error span tag is not showing anymore. Also i would like to get rid of the label wrapper around each input itself. Perhaps i would have to create a custom block in the initializers file? or maybe i am missing something in the block?

Here is my code

```
= f.simple_fields_for :answer_raiting do |builder|
  = builder.collection_radio_buttons(:response, AnswerRaiting::RAITING, :first, :last,
    collection_wrapper_tag: :div, collection_wrapper_class: "form-group radio-stars",
    item_wrapper_tag: false) do |b|
    = b.radio_button + fa_icon("star-o")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use `.error` method from `builder`:

```
builder.error :response
```

2) Let's see what happens when you use `collection_radio_buttons method`:

```
def collection_radio_buttons(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
  SimpleForm::Tags::CollectionRadioButtons.new(@object_name, method, @template, collection, value_method, text_method, objectify_options(options), @default_options.merge(html_options)).render(&block)
end
```

To skip wrapper over each item you can pass `item_wrapper_tag: nil` option.

To get rid of the wrappers you can read [this docs.](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers) 
Read about [custom components](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/adding-custom-input-components).

Comment: I have read about custom components but the problem here is that the input itself is built with the label wrapper

Comment: item_wrapper_tag: nil does not remove the label input wrapper

Comment: @adavia try to use `boolean_style: :inline` option

Comment: Awesome! boolean_style: :inline was the trick. btw is there any way to append builder.error :response inside the collection_wrapper_tag?

Comment: @adavia the way you can do it, is write custom input, without it you cannot append builder.error inside wrapper tag (probably you can, but it will be workaround)

Comment: Custom input or custom wrapper?

Comment: custom input, because wrappers are used when you call method `builder.input :something, as: :string`, when you call `collection_radio_buttons` it creates instance of class (see in answer) and use render method

Comment: see this https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb